# Mac say storage is full but it't not. iCloud drive takes 60 GB but I can't find any files

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

I hope this is the correct forum for this question and if not, I apologize.

Is it reasonable to have so little free space despite restoring mac? I have only Xcode and Mozilla installed, no movies, no music, no photos etc. Why do I have 30 GB of "other"
and 61 GB of "documents"?

Looking at the screenshot below, we see that the folder "iCloud Drive (Archive)" has a size of 61.02 GB, but it's subfolders are of sizes 8 KB and 1.5 MB respectively. I'm not the smartest dude in the world but I'm pretty sure that 8 KB + 1.5 MB does not equal 61.02 GB.

I've tried looking for these so called documents and bloat stuff everywhere but I can't find any. Has anyone ever had this problem and how did you solve it?

[image]